# AWK command to replace nth field from file1 to file2 at the nth line

Tags: shell, sed, awk, gawk

I have two files containing records as below:

`File1`:

```
1,2,3,a|x|z,4,5
```

And

`File2`:

```
1,2,3,a|x|z,4,5
1,2,3,a|x|z,4,5
1,2,3,a|x|z,4,5
1,2,3,a|x|z,4,5
```

Here there are 6 fields separated by `,`

How can I replace the fourth field(i.e. `a|x|z`) in 2nd, 3rd and 4th line of `File2` with a, x and z respectively from `File1`.

My real problem is, the fourth field wont be always `a|x|z` but it is always `|` separated

My considered output would be as below.

`File2`:

```
1,2,3,a|x|z,4,5
1,2,3,a,4,5
1,2,3,x,4,5
1,2,3,z,4,5
```

Comment: What did you try prior to asking here?

Comment: I removed the empty lines as you mention line numbers 2, 3, 4. If they were needed, you can roll back the edit.

Comment: No problem Lev. Its fine unless its well understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{split($4,f1,"|");next}FNR>1{$4=f1[FNR-1]}1' FS=, OFS=, file1 file2
1,2,3,a|x|z,4,5
1,2,3,a,4,5
1,2,3,x,4,5
1,2,3,z,4,5
```

Note: this assumes that number of sub-fields in `file1` *i.e 3* equals the number of lines to be replaced in `file2` *again 3 (lines 2,3,4)*. If this is not the case you should describe what should happen if says the number of sub fields is still 3 but the number of lines in file is 10?

Comment: Thanks a lot sudo :) I tried using split function but it always tried to replace the whole field. I think I need to learn more regarding awk!!!

Comment: Yup that is the problem I am facing right now. It works only on single record in file1, I am trying for multiple records by refering to the document by which you have shared the link above.